# Mod_Rewrite link to external url without parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

i changed my cms and have now some old urls, that are still linked by other websites.
Now i have to redirect the old links to my new sites Start Page.

The old CMS was installed in a subfolder named "contentms". The new CMS is installed in the root-folder.

Old Urls look like: mywebsite.com/contentms/content.php?idcat=62

When i try to forward it using my rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^contentms/.*$ http://www.mywebsite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

It works, but there will appear:
http://www.mywebsite.com/?idcat=62

But i want to have only http://www.mywebsite.com, without the "?idcat=62" added to the external url.

Maybe you have a solution for me. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try and see how it works for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/contentms
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mywebsite.com/? [R=301,L]
```

You can do this in the same line.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^contentms/.*$ http://www.mywebsite.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. This only works for:
    mywebsite.com/contentms/content.php

not for:
    mywebsite.com/contentms/content.php?idcat=62

In second case, there will appear a 404-Error.

Comment: @user3325687 Just add a `?` after the URL as in the second example.

Comment: Yes, the ? did it. Thanks.

Comment: OK, can you go ahead and accept the answer since it's resolved? Thanks